# No results found upon submitting and empty()

Tags: php, submit

So i've ran into a problem that internet searches cannot help. I am trying to figure a way to echo "no results found" when someone clicks submit and it comes up empty. I've done similar in the past, but cannot remember how I did it.
Here is what I have so far, and it doesn't work:

```
<?php
if ( empty($row_Recordset1) && isset($_POST['Submit']) ){
    echo "No results found";
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Better to provide info how you are passing value (accessing this from html) to this file.

Comment: Is $row_Recordset1 comes from form POST

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're forgetting to write a lot of code...
First of all, I'd suggest you to check $_POST['Submit'] at the beginning, so to understand if the page was loaded by simply opening the URL (directly writing it in your browser address bar or following a link from a previous page) or by click on form button:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
   // someone submitted the form
   // so, here you must check if results are available according to the submitted data

   //here all the necessary code to open a database connection, perform a mysql query  and save the results in $row_Recordset1

   //then you can check if the query returned no results
   if (empty($row_Recordset1) {
      echo "No results found"; 
   }
   else {
      // the code to print results here
   }

}
else {
   // no one submitted the form
   // so, here you should put the code to draw your html form
} 
?>
```